# (WordPress) How can I create custom pages tab?

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently, WordPress can create pages and posts.

How can I add 1 more tab for my articles?
Example:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/awesome_screenshot/6954136?AWSAccessKeyId=0R7FMW7AXRVCYMAPTPR2&Expires=1420552608&Signature=RUOQog3XkrQzV%2FVzvWf28K3js50%3D

Posts, Pages, Articles, Courses... all of them is content pages.

The intention is that I want to duplicate Posts to Posts & Articles.

It is possible to do this that?

Answer (score 0):

To add an administration menu, you must do three things:

1. Create a function that contains the menu-building code
2. Register the above function using the [admin_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_menu) action hook. (If you are adding an admin menu for the Network, use [network_admin_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/network_admin_menu) instead).
3. Create the HTML output for the page (screen) displayed when the menu item is clicked

If you need a Top-Bar menu, you need to use this code:

```
<?php add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position ); ?>
```

Check out [Administration Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus) for more details.

---

Also there's an awesome tutorial in [TutsPlus](http://code.tutsplus.com/) on how to edit the Wordpress Admin Sidebar:

[image]

Check out the full tutorial at [Customizing the WordPress Admin: Custom Admin Menus](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/customizing-the-wordpress-admin-custom-admin-menus--wp-33200)

Comment: This plugin change the "Posts" to "News".

I need Posts & News & Pages.